# JUnit testing with H2 database -java.lang.AssertionError

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, h2

I'm trying to write the Junit for the spring boot service implementation with h2 database but getting "java.lang.AssertionError", Please help and let me know where am i doing wrong

Please find below the project files:
src/test/resources/test.properties

```
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;sql.syntax_ora=true;
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.continueOnError=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.batch.initializer.enabled=true
```

src/test/resources/schema-h2.sql:

```
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE;

CREATE TABLE INLAND_CY (
    HUB_GEOID VARCHAR2(13) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    EFFECTIVE_DT TIMESTAMP,
    EXPIRY_DT TIMESTAMP,
    CREATED_DT TIMESTAMP,
    CREATED_BY  VARCHAR2(20) DEFAULT 'SYSTEM',
    LAST_UPDATED_DT TIMESTAMP,
    LAST_UPDATED_BY VARCHAR2(10)
    );


Insert into INLAND_CY (HUB_GEOID,EFFECTIVE_DT,EXPIRY_DT,CREATED_DT,LAST_UPDATED_DT,LAST_UPDATED_BY) values ('12345',to_date('01-01-2001','DD-MM-YYYY'),to_date('01-01-2099','DD-MM-YYYY'),to_date('01-01-2018','DD-MM-YYYY'),to_date('01-01-2018','DD-MM-YYYY'),'UPSTREAM');
Insert into INLAND_CY (HUB_GEOID,EFFECTIVE_DT,EXPIRY_DT,CREATED_DT,LAST_UPDATED_DT,LAST_UPDATED_BY) values ('12346',to_date('01-01-2001','DD-MM-YYYY'),to_date('01-01-2099','DD-MM-YYYY'),to_date('01-01-2018','DD-MM-YYYY'),to_date('01-01-2018','DD-MM-YYYY'),'UPSTREAM');
Insert into INLAND_CY (HUB_GEOID,EFFECTIVE_DT,EXPIRY_DT,CREATED_DT,LAST_UPDATED_DT,LAST_UPDATED_BY) values ('12347',to_date('01-01-2001','DD-MM-YYYY'),to_date('01-01-2099','DD-MM-YYYY'),to_date('01-01-2018','DD-MM-YYYY'),to_date('01-01-2018','DD-MM-YYYY'),'UPSTREAM');
```

TestConfig.java file:
    import javax.sql.DataSource;

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabase;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;

@TestConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource readDataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        EmbeddedDatabase db = builder
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL) //.H2 or .DERBY
                .addScript("/schema-h2.sql")
                .build();
        return db;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate readJdbcTemplate(DataSource readDataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(readDataSource);
    }
}
```

InlandPricingDAOImplTest.class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { TestConfig.class })
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class InlandPricingDAOImplTest {

    @Autowired
    InlandPricingDAOImpl inlandPricingDAOImpl;

    @Test
    public void testdfindgeotest1() throws IOException{
        InlandCY inlandCY=inlandPricingDAOImpl.findByHubgeoid("12346");
        System.out.println(inlandCY);
        assertNotNull(inlandCY);

    }

}
```

InlandPricingDAOImpl.class:

```
@Service
public class InlandPricingDAOImpl implements InlandPricingDAO {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource datasource;

    @Autowired
    InlandPricingRepository inlandPricingRepository;

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private InlandCY inlandCY;

    public void setDatasource(DataSource datasource) {
        this.datasource = datasource;
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
    }

    @Override
    public InlandCY findByHubgeoid(String hubgeoid) {
        return inlandPricingRepository.findByHubgeoid(hubgeoid);
    }
}
```

InlandPricingRepository interface:
    @Repository
    public interface InlandPricingRepository extends CrudRepository {
        public InlandCY findByHubgeoid(String hubgeoid);
    }

I'm getting null value from the service, i think the sql script is not running and adding data in h2 table. Please help and assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you didn't define your Service Bean in the TestConfiguration class. If the Bean is not defined there Autowiring will not be possible.

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse, but can you please tell more on this if possible as i'm very new to spring boot.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a little bit more of your actual implementation. I suppose the following prerequisite is given:

The class `InlandPricingDAOImpl` has a `@Component` annotation.

Then you should add a componentscan to your testConfiguration class like `@ComponentScan("your.package")` so that the Bean can be found.

Comment: Hi Christian, I have updated the question with impl class. please check whether i'm writing test configuration file properly as in the h2 table the data is not inserting. Thanks

Comment: So your service itself can be autowired but the data from the database is missing? If you need to run the sql script prior to your test add `@Sql(executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "classpath:schema-h2.sql")` to your InlandPricingDAOImplTest class